# String reverse in javascript using prototype

Tags: javascript

```
String.prototype.reverseStr = function () {
    var len = this.length - 1;
    var j = 0;
    for (i = len; i >= Math.floor(len / 2); i--) {
        var tmp = this[i];
        this[i] = this[j];
       this[j] = tmp;
       j++;
    }
    return this;
}

alert("abcde".reverseStr());
```

Why doesn't this work ? It outputs "abcde" and not reversed string  .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The same code but with some edits

```
String.prototype.reverseStr = function () {
    var len = this.length - 1;
    var tmp = '';
    for (var i = len; i >= 0; i--) {
        tmp += this[i];
    }
    return tmp;
}

alert("abcde".reverseStr());
```

See a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ons7o250/)

Answer (score 2):

Overkill.

```
 "abcde".split('').reverse().join('');
```

Comment: 1+ And it's surprisingly faster than most other methods too. (at least in modern browsers). http://jsperf.com/string-reverse/4

Comment: I got this . But what if I have write my own string function. Why doest the above code work.

Comment: @rrmo, Strings are immutable.